# Worksheet_Change returns wrong col number

Tags: vba, excel

What's wrong here? Whenever I chance a value in column L (=Col 12) this happens

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.Cells.Columns("A").Column .   'Prints 12 should be 1?!
End Sub
```

Comment: If `Target` is in column L, then its first column (i.e. its "A" column) is column 12 of the worksheet.  What are you trying to do?  If you are trying to refer to column "A" of the worksheet, that would be `Columns("A")`, not `Target.Columns("A")` (or the equivalent `Target.Cells.Columns("A")` that you have used).

Comment: When you refer to `Cells`, `Range`, `Columns`, `Rows` for your `Range` object, you effectively refer to these properties *relatively* to that `Range`. When you use them from `Worksheet` object, then these properties are relative to the whole sheet.

Comment: And it's not clear, why would you need to know that it's first column when you pass `A` and thus you know it's first column. Perhaps, you should point out what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks. That already helped to understand the difference between Target and Worksheet.

Comment: Best not to use column letters in references like this. "A" suggests that it would actually be Column A on the worksheet - but that's not the case, if your selected range ("Target") does not start in A.

Comment: How do I use a column name of a real table?